# External NOR Flash malfunctioning

Tags: microcontroller, eeprom, non-volatile-memory, nor-flash

**External NOR Flash malfunctioning**

Part used: **ZD25WQ16CTIGT Zetta NOR Flash**

We are using Zetta family 16MBit NOR Flash in a partitioned format. One partition is used as an emulated EEPROM, and another partition is used for data logging at regular intervals. As per our calculations, the write cycle limit of the part will not be reached in 3 years of operation in our use case.

Now that we have started deploying the product in the field from June 2023, most of our products are working fine. But in a small percentage (~0.1%) we have encountered some issues which are as follows:

1. When we write the data to Flash and read it, garbage data is read
   every time.
2. We write 0 to the whole page and then read it we get 0s,
   and then we write some data example 0xAA to the whole page and read
   it, we still get all 0s.

We are concerned that this issue would come up in more devices with more time. We wanted to understand possible reasons for this issue.

Comment: Just to be sure, when a page read back full of zeroes, you erased it before writing 0xAA to it? Or did you not erase the page?

Comment: Please add a link to the NOR flash datasheet.

Comment: @Rodo Link to the data sheet: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2109141830_Zetta-ZD25WQ16BTIGR_C2896790.pdf

Comment: @Justme Yes we are erasing the page using Page Erase command given in the data sheet prior to writing 0xAA

Comment: @EmbeddedEngineer Then consider a bug in somewhere, like not waiting for long enough for page erase or write to complete when sending next command, or some other bug, or hardware signal integrity error were maybe a clock edge is skipped or counted twice so writes are not byte aligned. Can you post schematics, PCB layout and code?

Comment: @Justme We are currently working to identify if there is any such bug, but we don't suspect there would be. Because if such a bug existed then it would occur more frequently and would be replicable. Also as far as I understand, if a sector or page of the flash goes bad the rest of the flash still stays intact right? Because we have a sector in our flash which remains untouched throughout lifetime. We partitioned it for some future use case but never got around to implement it.  But this unused sector also behaves like the other "used" sectors i.e. give garbage values upon reading.